# How to override schema of link in menu?

Tags: joomla-3.x

I am currently creating a template for Joomla v.3.9. The accordion menu is already included. For this I made an "Override" by copying the folder "mod_menu" into the template folder and adjusting it. So far so good.

Now I'm struggling to adjust the structure of the a-tag:

```
<li item-241 deeper parent><a href="#" title="changethecolor" class="fi-foot"> Rathaus</a>
```

I want to move the title-Attribute to the li-Tag. For example:

```
<li item-241 deeper parent background-color="changethecolor"><a href="#" class="fi-foot"> Rathaus</a>
```

At the moment, i'm looking for the right file to change it.

Maybe one of you can tell me which file I have to edit or how I have to start?!

Comment: Might it be simpler to just use javascript to move the attribute value?  Is `changethecolor` the actual text? or is it an actual color.  `background-color="changethecolor"` doesn't look like valid markup to me, but maybe it is for the template.  Do you no longer want the behavior that comes with `title` in the `<a>` tag?  If you want to recolor the listitem, maybe just use css.  Can you explain more about your coding intention?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I made an "Override" by copying the folder "mod_menu" into the template folder

You only need to copy files from `modules/mod_menu/tmpl/` folder, not the whole `modules/mod_menu/` folder. The files must be placed in `templates/your_template/html/mod_menu/`folder to be detected.

The folder contains the main `default.php` layout which loads a specific layout for each menu item based on menu item type. To remove the title, edit type-specific layouts (`default_component.php`, `default_heading.php`, `default_separator.php` and `default_url.php`). And to add title to `<li>` element edit the main layout.